# Change legacy Assets in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a problem changing my data in "Legacy Assets", I've tried several ways but I haven't gotten any positive results. I would like to know if there is any alternative to solve this.

I will add a print to illustrate better:

[image]

Comment: You have a "MapBIomas" folder, but the folder is empty. That's why the process is failing. With an asset inside the folder, the process should be `ee.data.copyAsset("projects/earthengine-legacy/assets/users/MapBiomas/assetName", "projects/ee-mwolf/assets/assetName")`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I added a .tiff file in the "MapBiomas" folder and it still appears that this operation does not exist...

Comment: Can you update the question to show more details?